# How sprite icon mechanism works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sprite, css-sprites

I want to understand how particular icon is loaded from a png file in the browser, by just specifying a name. Also how can I read the available icon names in the particular png file.

[image]

as an example, in this link,
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/templates  some specific icons are shown by specifying some names in the spriteclass, how to read the names from the file? I searched in Google and I didn't get proper detail about this.

[image]

From this png file, particular image is rendered just by specifying the a name (like "pdf", "image" and etc), from where can I read the names available in the png file? is there any tool or utility to read the available names from the png file?

Comment: The names are css classes, the css rules defines which part of the image sprite is shown. The png file itself does not have any names that's related to the html. Have a good read here http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites have nothing to do with JavaScript/jQuery. They are based on CSS properties.

You have a generic class which is responsible to order your browser to download a single image file

```
#treeview .k-sprite {
    background-image: url('../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png');
}
```

then you have a set of other CSS classes which play with `background-position` to find the desired image

```
.folder {
    background-position: 0px -16px;
}

.pdf {
    background-position: 0px -32px;
}
```

The image file acts as a matrix and you just have to play with the top left corner of each icon in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The names are not in the PNG, they are in the stylesheet (which specifies the `background-position` and some dimensions to crop the images with).

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you have a container width a smaller size than the image is. Say 20px by 20px. Then you set the sprite image as background image:

```
style="background-image: no-repeat 0px 0px url(sprite.png)";
```

Now only the first image in thh sprite will show, the others are hidden.

When you want to show the second, move the image 20px up:

```
style="background-position: 0px -20px";
```

In CSS you can set this to classes:

```
.icon-folder,
.icon-pdf,
.icon-file {
    background-image: no-repeat 0px 0px url(sprite.png);
}

.icon-pdf {
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

.icon-file {
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}
```